# docker returns err_empty_response when backend script takes too long

Tags: docker, fastapi

I am running a FastAPI application in docker. The backend is composed of multiple .py scripts, which train several machine learning models. The FastAPI returns the results. I have docker running and everything is just fine. However, when the modeling takes longer (by using several hyperparameter search loops), I receive an err_empty_response from my dockerized App. Without docker everything is fine. I suppose, it is some timeout issue.
I have added "shutdown-timeout": 600 in the  config.v2.json file in var/lib/docker/containers (I am on ubuntu 18.04), but this did not help.
This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=Europe/Moscow
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl wget gcc build-essential
#install python 3.9
RUN apt update
RUN apt install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt install python3.9 -y
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python
# install conda
RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.12-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && \
     /bin/bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda
# create env with python 3.9
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda create -y -n myenv python=3.9
RUN apt install -y -q build-essential python3-pip python3-dev
RUN pip3 install -U pip setuptools wheel
#install python environment/libraries
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
ENV PATH=/opt/conda/envs/myenv/bin:$PATH
RUN pip3 install gunicorn uvloop httptools
RUN pip3 install -r /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -U kaleido
COPY projectfolder/ /projectfolder/
RUN ls -la /projectfolder/*
WORKDIR /projectfolder
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT /opt/conda/envs/myenv/bin/gunicorn \
  -b 0.0.0.0:80 \
  -w 4 \
  -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app \
  --chdir /projectfolder
```

This is a sample FastAPI app, just for demo. The sleep time mimicks the timeout:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn
app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    time.sleep(150)
    return {"message": "Hello World from docker"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

I launch docker with

```
sudo docker build -t myproject .
sudo docker run -it --rm --name my-running-app -p 80:80  myproject
```

and open localhost in chrome.

So the question is: how can I extend the timeout, if this is the issue (most likely)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after experimenting a bit, I found out that the issue was not with docker timeout, but with FastAPI. To change that, I modified the Entrypoint definiton in the dockerfile and set the timeout setting:

```
ENTRYPOINT /opt/conda/envs/myenv/bin/gunicorn \
  -b 0.0.0.0:80 \
  -w 4 \
  --timeout 600 \
  -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app
```